# Laravel group routing parameters with prefix

Tags: php, laravel-4

I've noticed that the parameters that you specify in a route prefix within a group are also supplied to all controllers that sit within that particular group which makes sense.

For example:

```
Route::group(array('prefix' => 'team/{id}/{slug}', 'before' => 'auth'), function () {
Route::get('documents/{document}', 'controllers\\team\\DocumentsController@show');
});
```

The DocumentsController's show method then has to follow the order of all parameters:

`show($id, $slug, $document)`

However, I don't really need the Team id and slug  in the DocumentsController, they're just for pretty URLS. Is there anyway to pass only the parameters specified for that route to the DocumentsController (i.e. exclude the prefix params), as follows:

```
show($document)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can parse the route pattern before it hits the controllers.

You would do this in the boot() method.

This is a very intricate problem to fix, but I can give you a little guidance.  Take a look at 'Illuminate\Routing\Route'  and there is a function `setPattern()` in the Route class you should look at.

Comment: Thankyou for the advice. For the time being I've been using Route::getCurrentRoute()->getParameter('document') but parsing sounds more sensible given that I have this problem across many controllers so I'll give it a shot.